# T-SQL get columns of specific type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get names of columns with a specific type (so I can dynamically query the result). Code below seems to be getting me close (with i.e. type=56 standing for int) but it just seems to be incorrect. Not to mention that I've failed to find a good mapping from types to int representation.

```
SELECT c.system_type_id as type
FROM SYS.COLUMNS c
JOIN SYS.TABLES t ON c.object_id = t.object_id   
WHERE t.name = 'MyTableName'
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you tell us what is wrong with your query, we cannot help you very much.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? What's specifically wrong with the query that you're using? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wanted to get the mapping with the type name (i.e 56 = 'int'). JPW has already directed me how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the mapping to types in the `sys.types` catalog view:

```
SELECT c.name as column_name, ty.name as type_name
FROM SYS.COLUMNS c
JOIN SYS.TABLES t ON c.object_id = t.object_id   
JOIN SYS.TYPES ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'MyTableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type'
FROM    
    sys.columns c INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN     sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server you can do something like this;

```
DECLARE @DataType varchar(20); SET @DataType = 'int'

SELECT
    o.name TableName
    ,c.name ColumnName
    ,t.name ColumnType
    ,t.max_length ColumnLength
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o
    ON c.object_id = o.object_id
JOIN sys.types t
    ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id 
WHERE t.name LIKE '%' + @DataType + '%'
    AND o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```

Just change the data type in the variable and it will give you a list like this

```
TableName   ColumnName  ColumnType  ColumnLength
Employees   empid       int         4
Employees   mgrid       int         4
Suppliers   supplierid  int         4
Categories  categoryid  int         4
Products    productid   int         4
Products    supplierid  int         4
```

You can modify this to add in the table name if that's what you want to do.